# Firebase Auth - Are "Restore E-Mail-Address"-mails sent when changing the e-mail via the Admin API?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I understand from the docs that if I change the e-mail-address of a user via the client, i.e. using something like `user.updateEmail()`, a restore e-mail is sent to the old address automatically. Does this also happen when updating a user via the Admin API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Firebase Auth Admin API directly updates user's email address without sending the emails.